# What is the difference between these two nodes?

Tags: java, nodes

I have a source of two different nodes, code below:

```
public class Jazel {
    int data;
    Jazel levo;
    Jazel desno;

    public Jazel(int vdata){
        data = vdata;
        levo = null;
        desno = null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class JazelL {
    int data;
    JazelL next;

    public JazelL(int vdata){
        data = vdata;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the difference between these two nodes?

Comment: um... the first one stores a reference to two other nodes (presumably a "next" one and a "last" one, as in a doubly linked list), and the second only stores a reference to the "next" one, as in a singly linked list

Comment: When you say "node", do you mean class? The class names are different and you have different members in the classes.

Comment: One has a "levo" and "desno" whereas the other has only a "next"... ?

Comment: I think `node` means `node (of a graph)`, since Google told me that levo means left and desno means right. So I agree with Steven's answer and would say that the first class is used to model a binary tree and the second for a simple linked list.

Comment: You should at least translate the names in the code before posting it.

Comment: So, the difference is that the first class is a doubly linked list and the second one is a singly linked list. That was what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're for different data structures. The first is for a binary tree, the second is for a linked list.

Comment: Question: Is binary tree and doubly linked list the same?

Comment: No. [Binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the first class refers "left" and "right" nodes and stores data - it is a binary tree node. Second class stores data and refers "next" node - it is a singly linked list node.